# Magic in navigation between views in ASP.NET MVC 5 Single Page Application template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, single-page-application

I'm inspecting ASP.NET MVC 5 Single Page Application project template in Visual Studio 2013.
And I'm trying to understand how navigation between views is handled.
I can't get anything about that in code (yes, there is a View property in global view model and navigation methods change it, but where this view is used?).

But trying things at practice, I've found out that such comments at the beginning and at the end are important and if they are absent - this particular view will be shown all the time. if they are present - then only if `bindingMemberName` matches it will be shown.

```
<!-- ko with: bindingMemberName -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

How these comments can control the appearance of the view???

Comment: Have you read the relevant part of the KO documentation http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html ?

Comment: Oh, I've missed last part of it. Thatnks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

in the app.viewmodel.js file you will find

```
if (typeof (options.navigatorFactory) !== "undefined") {
        navigator = options.navigatorFactory(self, dataModel);
    } else {
        navigator = function () {
            window.location.hash = options.bindingMemberName;
        };
    }

    // Add navigation member to AppViewModel (for example, app.NavigateToHome());
    self["navigateTo" + options.name] = navigator;
```

which builds a list of functions that navigate for you, note that at the bottom of the home.viewmodel.js file (and any you add yourself) will have to contain

```
app.addViewModel({
   name: "Home",
   bindingMemberName: "home",
   factory: HomeViewModel
})
```

which ties it together.